# C function to fully consume a Python iterator

Tags: python, c, reinventing-the-wheel, iterator, ffi

I was reading into the proper way to consume an iterator on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36763084/how-to-efficiently-exhaust-an-iterator-in-a-oneliner) as well as [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2013-September/023488.html) and I notices there is no actual proper function for this that clearly explains itself.

Using:

```
collections.deque(maxlen=0).extend(iterable)
```

isn't exactly very descriptive whereas making a properly named method for this that just uses the `deque` approach is good I wanted to do my own research as well as learn some c *(which I've rarely ever actually dealt with)* along the way.

So.. Using the approach that is used in [_collectionsmodule.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a1952122a3a20272e4db9e3c6205009a91c73ccf/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c#L368) I have come up with this:

```
#include "Python.h"
#include <ctype.h>

static PyObject *
consume(PyObject *self, PyObject *iterable)
{
    PyObject *(*iternext)(PyObject *);
    PyObject *item;

    if (PyObject_GetIter(iterable) == NULL)
        return NULL;

    iternext = *Py_TYPE(iterable)->tp_iternext;
    while ((item = iternext(iterable)) != NULL)
        Py_DECREF(item);

    if (PyErr_Occurred()) {
        if (PyErr_ExceptionMatches(PyExc_StopIteration))
            PyErr_Clear();
        else
            return NULL;
    }
    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}

static PyMethodDef consumeMethods[] = {
    {"consume", (PyCFunction)consume, METH_O,
      "Run an iterator to exhaustion."},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

static struct PyModuleDef _consumemodule = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "_consumemodule",
    "Consume Module",
    -1,
    consumeMethods,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC
PyInit__consumemodule(void)
{
    return PyModule_Create(&_consumemodule);
}
```

It performs marginally better than the deque approach which is expected as it's using almost the same approach although I was wondering if any of the c guru's out there could see if I'm missing anything or if something could be done better as all it's doing it exhausting the iterator. I tried using `METH_FASTCALL` but that doesn't perform as well as `METH_O` and in the `while` loop I tried using`while ((Py_XDECREF(iternext(iterable))) != NULL)` the only way I could find to eliminate the need for the variable `item` was by making a macro like this:

```
static inline int _Ret_DECREF(PyObject *op)
{
    if (op == NULL)
        return 0;
    Py_DECREF(op);
    return 1;
}

#define Ret_DECREF(op) _Ret_DECREF(op)
```

Then just looping through like this:

```
while (1) {
    if (Ret_DECREF(iternext(iterable)))
        break;
}
```

But something just feels off doing that.

Comment: I'm tagging this [tag:reinventing-the-wheel] as you can just use [the itertools recipe that you were linked to](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes). Alternately you could just use [`more_itertools.consume`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.consume) - which uses the exact same code.

Comment: Understood, I’m fully aware that’s what I’m doing, although I’m looking to see if there’s any room for improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’ve got an object leak.

[`PyObject_GetIter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html?highlight=pyobject_getiter#c.PyObject_GetIter) returns a new instance, which you aren’t calling `Py_DECREF()` on.

If you pass in an **iterable** object to your function (a list, a tuple, a dictionary, etc), `PyObject_GetIter()` will return a brand new **iterator** over than object.  You test the return value, discover it is not `NULL`, and then lose the returned value, since it was not stored in a local variable.  Then, you try to retrieve `tp_iternext` from the iterable’s type, which is likely not defined, so chaos will ensue.

If you pass in an **iterator** object to your function, `PyObject_GetIter()` will return it, but also increment the reference count of that object by one.  At the end of your function, you don’t call `Py_DECREF()` on the returned iterator, so the reference count will remain incremented, and the iterator will never be released.

```
static PyObject *
consume(PyObject *self, PyObject *iterable)
{
    PyObject *(*iternext)(PyObject *);
    PyObject *item;
    PyObject *iterator;

    iterator = PyObject_GetIter(iterable);  // No references to iterable beyond this point.
    if (iterator == NULL)
        return NULL;

    iternext = *Py_TYPE(iterator)->tp_iternext;
    while ((item = iternext(iterator)) != NULL) 
        Py_DECREF(item);

    Py_DECREF(iterator);

    if (PyErr_Occurred()) {
        if (PyErr_ExceptionMatches(PyExc_StopIteration))
            PyErr_Clear();
        else
            return NULL;
    }

    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great breakdown and helpful answer although, this is exactly the same as is used in the `deque`'s `consume_iterator` and that may just be the best option but what I was thinking was to see if there is a better alternative that doesn’t need to store `item` for every iteration. I’ve tried `do { Py_DECREF(iternext(iterator)) } while (!PyErr_Occurred())` but maybe my lack of c knowledge is making me think that there’s a better option while there isn’t.

Comment: @Jab If you look at `consume_iterator`, you’ll see it ends with `return finalize_iterator(it);`, and in **that** is the `Py_DECREF(it);`.  I understand you were hoping for a speed improvement, not a bug fix, but there is a bug in your code and I’ve showed you how to fix it.  The `consume_iterator` function doesn’t have the bug because it calls the additional helper function to clean up the iterator reference.  You didn’t copy that part into your implementation.

Comment: I must have taken that out by mistake as I did look at those docs and saw it did make a new reference before even posting this too. Thanks for showing me

Comment: Your `do { ... } while ( )` loop doesn’t work because `iternext(iterator)` will return `NULL` which will cause `Py_DECREF(...)` to crash.  You would need to use `Py_XDECREF(...)` which allows the argument to be `NULL`.

Comment: I meant `Py_XDECREF` I’m on my phone away from the desk. Although when I tried that I believe it was an infinite loop or it only ran the first iteration I’ll have to try again when I get back to see.

Comment: Note: [`PyIter_Next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/iter.html?highlight=pyiter_next#c.PyIter_Next) does **NOT** set the `PyExc_StopIteration` error when the end of a iterator is reached; it merely returns `NULL`.  The [tp_iternext](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html?highlight=tp_iternext#c.PyTypeObject.tp_iternext) method documentation reads "_When the iterator is exhausted, it must return `NULL`; a `StopIteration` exception **may or may not be set**._" (emphasis mine).  This may be the source of your endless loop.  You must test for the `NULL` return value.